# Excel Macros Average

Tags: vba, excel, average

Im trying to the get the average of a column but this throws a Syntax Error and i can't get my head round it

```
Sheets("Calculator").Range("C15").Value = "=Average(Sheets("Results").Range("C2:C1000"))"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try resolving it in vba.

```
Sheets("Calculator").Range("C15").Value = application.Average(Sheets("Results").Range("C2:C1000"))
```

Or as a formula on the worksheet.

```
Sheets("Calculator").Range("C15").formula = "=average(" & Sheets("Results").Range("C2:C1000").address(0, 0, external:=true) & ")"
```

Comment: Do you which of `Application.Average` or `WorksheetFunction.Average` is better?

Comment: Ahhh yes this worked for me thank you it's been annoying me for ages now

Comment: Isn't `Sheets("Results").Range("C2:C1000").address …` a bit overpowered if you just could use a string `Results!C2:C1000`?

Comment: I prefer application since you can resolve errors returned instead of throwing them. A #DIV/0! can be caught with IsError with application; worksheetfunction just stops.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ - only if you knew the string beforehand.

Comment: i need it from a different sheet though thats why i have Sheets("Results")

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Sheets("Calculator").Range("C15").Formula = "=Average(Results!C2:C1000)"
```

Or this:

```
Sheets("Calculator").Range("C15").Value = WorksheetFunction.Average(Sheets("Results").Range("C2:C1000"))
```